# Using the camera via UIImagePickerController crashes on iPod

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ipod

My application crashes when I open the camera on my iPod. I used `UIImagePickerController` for this. The app works fine on an iPhone.

What could cause the error?

Comment: If possible, please provide more information about the crash. Do you see any traces/logs or anything else that might help identify the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use +isSourceTypeAvailable: method in UIImagePickerController:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   // Has camera
```

Comment: I don't understand why this crashes on an iPod touch that has a camera?